# Navigation with hierarchy feature for proper user understanding of the overall structure of the program

Tags: wpf

I am trying to achieve this kind of navigation with hierarchy in WPF.
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/79

*Apparently, the link above is a proposal for UWP navigation control i've been trying to create.

I have tried using listbox view with groupstyle for items with hierarchy and for others that does not have submenu. However I am not able to achieve it properly.

Is there a similar control or toolkit where I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use toolkits!

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

use MaterialDesign expander, treeview, hamburgmenu etc..